# Process to build our own model for image detection

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

Currently, I am working on deep neural network for image detection and I founded a model called YOLO Network, and it's very powerful to make objects detections, but I have a question:

- How can we design and concept our own model?  Do we use a brut force for that, for example "I use 2 convolutional and 1 pooling layer and 1 fully connected layer" after that if the result is'nt good I change the number of layers and change the parameter until I find the best model, Please if there is anyone who knows some informations about that, show me how ?

I use Tensorflow.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of papers addressing this issue. For example in http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Szegedy_Rethinking_the_Inception_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf some general principles are mentioned, like preserving information by not having too rapid changes in any cut of the graph seperating the output from the input.

Another paper is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.02228.pdf where specific hyperparameter combinations are tried.

The remainder are just what you observe in practice and depends on your dataset and on your requirement. Maybe you have performance requirements because you want to deploy to mobile or you need more than 90 % accuracy. Then you will have to choose your model accordingly.